# ERROR for Corda Settler in Docker: Failed to deserialise group OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 in transaction

Tags: docker, corda

I dockerized the Corda Settler and started the flow `UpdateSettlementMethod` using RPC due to the error mentioned here https://github.com/corda/corda-settler/issues/21.

However, I am facing the following error:

```
net.corda.core.internal.TransactionDeserialisationException: Failed to deserialise group OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 in transaction: Internal deserialization failure: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.r3.corda.finance.ripple.types.XrpSettlement
        at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt:82) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.internal.LazyMappedList.get(InternalUtils.kt:552) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:581) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.plus(_Collections.kt:1970) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at net.corda.core.internal.Verifier.<init>(TransactionVerifierServiceInternal.kt:33) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction$internalPrepareVerify$1.invoke(LedgerTransaction.kt:148) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction$internalPrepareVerify$1.invoke(LedgerTransaction.kt:45) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder$withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$1.invoke(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:339)
~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:71) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:338) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.AttachmentsClassLoaderBuilder.withAttachmentsClassloaderContext$default(AttachmentsClassLoader.kt:314) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.internalPrepareVerify$core(LedgerTransaction.kt:144) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:134) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addMissingDependency(TransactionBuilder.kt:186) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core(TransactionBuilder.kt:166) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core(TransactionBuilder.kt:169) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core(TransactionBuilder.kt:169) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core$default(TransactionBuilder.kt:134) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:131) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toSignedTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:711) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:232) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:246) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.signInitialTransaction(AbstractNode.kt:962) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:268) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.signInitialTransaction(AbstractNode.kt:962) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.client.flows.UpdateSettlementMethod$Initiator.call(UpdateSettlementMethod.kt:77) ~[?:?]
        at com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.client.flows.UpdateSettlementMethod$Initiator.call(UpdateSettlementMethod.kt:22) ~[?:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:329) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:314) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at cdm.swap.flows.NovateAndUpdate.call(NovateAndUpdate.kt:72) ~[?:?]
        at cdm.swap.flows.NovateAndUpdate.call(NovateAndUpdate.kt:18) ~[?:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:269) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Internal deserialization failure: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.r3.corda.finance.ripple.types.XrpSettlement
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:106) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:119) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:225) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:71) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:73) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:85) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt:78) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.r3.corda.finance.ripple.types.XrpSettlement
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.TypeIdentifier$Unparameterised.getLocalType(TypeIdentifier.kt:149) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1$1.apply(TypeLoader.kt:38) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1$1.apply(TypeLoader.kt:25) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1.invoke(TypeLoader.kt:38) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader$load$noCarpentryRequired$1.invoke(TypeLoader.kt:25) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.putAll(Maps.kt:339) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.toMap(Maps.kt:504) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at kotlin.collections.MapsKt__MapsKt.toMap(Maps.kt:498) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.model.ClassCarpentingTypeLoader.load(TypeLoader.kt:45) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory.reflect(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:130) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory.access$reflect(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:48) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory$get$1.invoke(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:72) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory$get$1.invoke(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:48) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultDescriptorBasedSerializerRegistry.getOrBuild(DescriptorBasedSerializerRegistry.kt:28) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DefaultRemoteSerializerFactory.get(RemoteSerializerFactory.kt:67) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposedSerializerFactory.get(SerializerFactory.kt) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject$serialization(DeserializationInput.kt:172) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$serialization(DeserializationInput.kt:147) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DescribedTypeReadStrategy.readProperty(ComposableTypePropertySerializer.kt:202) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableTypePropertySerializer.readProperty(ComposableTypePropertySerializer.kt) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectReader$readObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:140) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectReader$readObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:122) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectReader.readObject(ObjectSerializer.kt:219) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectSerializer.readObject(ObjectSerializer.kt:91) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject$serialization(DeserializationInput.kt:182) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$serialization(DeserializationInput.kt:147) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DescribedTypeReadStrategy.readProperty(ComposableTypePropertySerializer.kt:202) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableTypePropertySerializer.readProperty(ComposableTypePropertySerializer.kt) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectReader$readObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:140) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectReader$readObject$$inlined$ifThrowsAppend$lambda$1.invoke(ObjectSerializer.kt:122) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectReader.readObject(ObjectSerializer.kt:219) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.ComposableObjectSerializer.readObject(ObjectSerializer.kt:91) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObject$serialization(DeserializationInput.kt:182) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.readObjectOrNull$serialization(DeserializationInput.kt:147) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput$deserialize$1.invoke(DeserializationInput.kt:124) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:99) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:119) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:225) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:71) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:73) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:85) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt:78) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        ... 48 more
```

The internal deserialization occurs when the party trys to sign the transaction.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue due to the tightening of contract constraints in Corda 4. Ensure that you are using at latest Corda version 4.1 and that all the required attachments are in the cordapps folder.

Comment: Hi Roger, thank you for your response! I'm using the official Corda-Zulu docker image of 4.1, so I hope that's the latest version. Is there a way to verify it? Which attachments are required for the Corda Settler that I have to provide manually to the cordapps folder? Currently, I placed in the cordapps folder all the jar files that are placed there, when you run the nodes locally, exept of the Swift-jar and the Manual-jar, since I am not using those.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't really advise without be able to repro it on my end. I'll have a look tomorrow and see what I can come up with. I'm sure it's a subtle annoying thing. Do you get the same issues if you clone the repo and try to use it locally on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I got the same issue, when I cloned the repo and and run it locally. The only thing that I changed, was that I wrote wrappers to start the flows.

Comment: Hey Roger, did you have time to look into it and could you reproduce the error?